# Why two cursor in input type text - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, text, input

I have a input type text which looks like this

```
<input name="po" class="input-tablet-field ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-numberformatter 
ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" id="po" required="" type="text" 
readonly="" step="0.01" placeholder="Value" data-ng-click="nm.clickInput()" 
data-ng-model="etModel" data-ng-disabled="etDisabled" 
data-ng-model-options="{debounce: 300}" data-ng-blur="blur($event)" 
data-ng-focus="focus($event)" numberformatter="etNumberFormatter" 
data-ng-keydown="nm.keyInput($event)" 
selectedchannel="controller.selectedChannel" numberformatdata="getNumberFormatData()">
```

And i have span next to input text

```
<span class="left">
    <div class="tC" data-ng-show="numPad.isFocused(processOffsetForm.processOffset)"></div> 
</span>
```

The input text looks like this..

[image]

We can see the two cursor appearing before and after text..  How to remove cursor appearing before text

Comment: make plunker please and Is the first one is really a cursor or anything like border of the element? Is that blinking?

Comment: There's no way to know the cause of this from the code you provided. Have you tried inspecting the HTML element? Check if it has borders and also check for ::before and ::after, maybe they have borders. That could be the cause.

Comment: Those are not borders. Both are blinking.. and they are cursors

Comment: Please provide code through plunker or fiddle

Comment: making two cursors blink in plunker or fiddle is difficult.. because there are so many custom directives which have written for this input as u can see..  what might have been the possibility for this?

Comment: Did you create any custom cursors?

Comment: No i did not create any custom cursor..  u can see the input text attributes

Comment: Then there is no way to have two cursors. It is definitely not a cursor then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145524/discussion-between-matarishvan-and-mr-perfect).